# How can a shell process started from a macOS application use functions defined in ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: bash, macos, process, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have defined a function in `~/bash_profile` named `dotnet`. The function acts as a stand-in for the actual executable, and instead runs the [microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) Docker container, passing along any options. Means I don't have the actual .NET Core tools installed on my machine. This works great in bash (on macOS).

But it doesn't work in the [OmniSharp](http://www.omnisharp.net) extension in Visual Studio Code. The extension uses its [execChildProcess function](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/6013d9214d58d5ee34a539a62ab7074d56fad547/src/common.ts#L44) to execute `dotnet --info` ([link to code](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/26508b3b3a27b42e6fc1c5883948686723385007/src/coreclr-debug/util.ts#L87)), but it fails. Looking at the code it uses Node.js' `child_process` module to 'shell out'

How can I make it so that the functions defined in `~/.bash_profile` are also available to the shell process started from Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Generally speaking, writing your scripts to depend on user-specific configuration is a bad idea -- it makes those scripts unusable by other users, so you can't just post them online as-is or copy them from machine to machine. Is there a reason you aren't just bundling the functions into the script?

Comment: (Also, there are a number of circumstances where shell functions won't work whatsoever -- if `sh -c` is used and is implemented by a non-bash shell such as ash or dash it won't read `.bash_profile`, might not understand any extended syntax used there even if you told it to, and can't understand exported functions even if they're present in the environment; `find ... -exec dotnet` doesn't invoke any shell at all, so it won't work there; etc; you're better off putting a shim in your PATH if you want something that works everywhere).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for linking my question to one that is similar. The answer I found there (to export the function) fixed my issue.